# One instance of service per module

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2.x application with multiple feature modules. All these modules make use of a custom http service which is injected into other services.

In our test environment I would like to be able to disable post/put/delete requests for some of the modules that are not yet ready. I thought that I could do that by making a sublass of the http service where the requests should be disabled  and use

`providers: [{provide: AuthHttp, useClass: moduleHttp}]`

for that module but that doesn't seem to work. It seems like the first AuthHttp provided is used by all other modules. Is it possible for each module to have its own instance of the service?

Comment: You can either make your features modulse lazy or provide token within component metadata.

Comment: How do I provide a token with component metadata?

Comment: `@Component({selector: 'some-selector', providers: [{}]`

Comment: Read also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-component-scoped-providers